# Spring Kafka polling using Consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using consumer.poll(Duration d) for fetching the records. I have only 10 records for testing purpose in Kafka topic spread across 6 partitions. I have disabled auto commit and not committing manually either (again for testing purpose only). When poll is executed it is not fetching data from all partitions. I need to run the poll in a loop to get all the data. I haven't overridden the parameters like max.poll.size or max.fetch.bytes from its default values. What could be the reason? Please note that I have only this consumer for the given topic and group id hence I hope all the partitions will be assigned to this

```
private Consumer<String, Object> createConsumer() {
    ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory = deadLetterConsumerFactory();
    Consumer<String, Object> consumer = consumerFactory.createConsumer();
    consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(kafkaConfigProperties.getDeadLetterTopic()));
    return consumer;
}

try {
       consumer = createConsumer();
       ConsumerRecords<String, Object> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(5000));
       processMessages (records , .,....);
} catch (Exception e) {
       ....
} finally {
     if (consumer != null) {
          consumer.unsubscribe();
          consumer.close();
      }
}
```

EDIT
Here is the details

```
ConsumerFactory<String, Object> deadLetterConsumerFactory() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, server);
    properties.put(SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL, url);
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG,
           "myid" + "-" + CONSUMER_CLIENT_ID_SEQUENCE.getAndIncrement());
    properties.put(SSL_ENDPOINT_IDFN_ALGM,  alg);
    properties.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, saslmech);
    properties.put(REQUEST_TIMEOUT,  timeout);       
    properties.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, config);
    properties.put(SECURITY_PROTOCOL,  protocol);
     properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
    consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "groupid");
    consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    consumerProperties.forEach((key, value) -> {
        map.put((String) key, value);
    });
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(map);
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `@KafkaListener`? And please describe the consumer group to prove your client has all partitions assigned to it

Comment: I don't want Kafka listener at this time. I connect to Kafka using consumer as part of a REST service call. This dead letter topic will not have much messages in it and there is no continuous flow into it. So I am fine with connect-disconnect pattern.

Comment: Alright fine. Please address the rest of my comment

Comment: @cricket_007, please see my edits

Comment: Are you familiar with `kafka-consumer-groups` command? That is what I asked for, but thanks for the edit

Comment: If you are only polling once there is no guarantee that you will get any records. First time you poll, partitions get assigned (synchronously) and data  is requested from the Fetcher, but once there is an assignment then the Fetcher pre-fetches using the heartbeat thread. On the first poll, I'd probably expect some records but maybe not, and I'd never use a single poll call with any expectations. Why not put a breakpoint in the poll method of KafkaConsumer and see what happens